# React - Render <Link> with style

Tags: css, reactjs

Sorry if this is too basic, I'm new to React.

I am trying to import some CSS (which consists of an animation), like so:

```
import './css/mug.css'
```

**mug.css**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,400);

body {
  background:rgb(223,189,150);
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

.cup {
  width:76px;
  height:76px;
  background:#dedede;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-38px;
  top:100px;
  box-shadow:-4px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cup:after{
  content:"";
  width:66px;
  height:66px;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:linear-gradient(-45deg, #cbcbcb, #f2f2f2 );
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-33px;
  top:5px;
}

.coffee{
  width:47px;
  height:47px;
  background:#613317;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(15deg, transparent 0px, transparent 29px, rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 29px, rgba(255,255,255,0.05) 47px);*/
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-25px;
  z-index:1;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-26px;
  border:3px solid #e9e9e9;
  box-shadow:-3px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transform:rotate(30deg);
  transition:transform 0.3s;
}

.coffee:after{ /*assa*/
 content:"";
  width:15px;
  height:8px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-19px;
  top:18px;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, #d6d6d6, #aeaeae);
  box-shadow:0px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.coffee:before {
  content:"";
  width:47px;
  height:47px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), -webkit-radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 95%), -moz-radial-gradient(5% 9%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), transparent 5%), -moz-radial-gradient(0% 0%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent 55%);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.cup:hover .coffee {
  transform:rotate(15deg);
}

.smoke {
  width:70px;
  height:100px; 
  background:;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-40px;
  top:43px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -webkit-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -webkit-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), -webkit-radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -moz-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -moz-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), -moz-radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%), radial-gradient(55% 35%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%);
  animation:bk 11s infinite ;
}

.smoke:after {
  content:"";
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 
  background:;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -webkit-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -webkit-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), -moz-radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), -moz-radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(75% 59%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 25%), radial-gradient(25% 70%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 15%), radial-gradient(35% 61%, ellipse, rgba(255,255,255,0.2), transparent 10%);
  animation:bk 2s 1s infinite;
}


@keyframes bk {
  0%{ background-position:0 0; opacity:0; }
  15%, 85% { opacity:1;}
  100%{ background-position:-20px -25px, -5px -25px, 0px -25px, 0px -25px; opacity:0;}
}

.txt{
  position:absolute;
  top:184px;
  width:150px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-75px;
}

.txt a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#613317;
}

.txt a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

render (animate it) it like so:

```
    <div>
        <div className="cup">
            <div className="coffee"></div>
    </div>
        <div className="smoke"></div>
```

and add this style to `<Link>`

```
const Brewing = (props) => (
        <div>
            <Link 
                to="/brewing">Brew
                style=? 
            </Link>
        </div>
  )

export default Brewing;
```

I can't simply add multiple classes like so:

```
var myClassNames = "cup coffee smoke"
```

and pass it to style:

```
style={myClassNames}
```

because "coffee" is contained by "cup".

So how do I add this style and render it properly to my link when it is clicked?

Comment: why would you want to give all those classnames to your link? I'm a bit confused with your question. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: because it is an animation, and one <div> must be contained by other. I'll add CSS so you can see it.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Link is getting converted to `a` tag which is only 1 and your animation contains 3 div's. So I think it is not possible.

Comment: Why? Because it worked perfectly when I use server side templating, simply pointing to an html file. I assumed JavaScript had at least the same power for design purposes

Comment: But only passing classnames, how it will get converted to nested div structure? In your server side templating this div structure is might be already present.

Comment: Inside of `Link` tag try to add your div structure directly.

Comment: I used Jinja2 templating with Flask’s render_trmplate(brewing.html), and in html filé nested divs

Comment: @ravibagul91 that I’ve tried, and it does render, but css is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

For any web development use `react-router-dom`, then use `NavLink` which contains attribute of `activeClassName`.

```
...
<NavLink to="/brewing" activeClassName="cup coffee smoke">
  Brewing
</NavLink>
...
```

Here's link to [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink).

Comment: this is not working. `CSS` is messed up with `<Link>`, but it renders. with `<NavLink`, nothing is rendered.